# Actualizar automáticamente un Chart o DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql-server, update

En mi sistema que es un punto de venta tengo varios paneles. Lo que pasa es que si ya tengo el panel abierto con un `DGV` y `Chart` y abro el `CRUD` de productos y empiezo ingresar o eliminar productos no se me actualiza automáticamente el `DGV` ni el `Chart` hasta que cierre y abra de nuevo el panel donde están.

Ya probé llamando los métodos de `Refresh` y `Update`.

Por ejemplo, cuando oprima al evento de botón para abrir el `Form` donde esta el `DGV` y el `Chart`.

```
FORMREPORTES reportes = new FORMREPORTES();
reportes.Update();
reportes.Refresh();
```

No sé, tengo entendido que cuando se abre el `Form` se crea la instancia de `DGV` y del `Chart` y esto solo se actualizaran cuando reinicie el `Form`, pero me imagino que existe alguna forma para que esta instancia se actualice.

Lo que hice y funciona pero hasta que vuelva a oprimir al `Form` es crear el evento y colocar el método para actualizar el `DGV`.

```
private void TABLAPRODUCTOS_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CN_Productos objecto = new CN_Productos();
    TABLAPRODUCTOS.DataSource = objecto.MostrarProductos();
}
```

Comment: No se si te entiendo, pero has probado a crear un timer y volver a asignar el `DataSource` en el evento tick del mismo?

Comment: Realiza una consulta a `BD` y asigna el `DataSource`, luego de haber ejecutado exitosamente la inserción, eliminación o actualización del registro. El problema es que cuando abres por primera vez la web se carga inicialmente el `DataGridView` con la primera consulta de la página pero recuerda que cada vez que modificas, eliminas o agregas un registro debes actualizar también tus datos en el `DataGridView` por lo que necesitas realizar otra vez una consulta para obtener los datos actualizados.

Comment: Lo otro que puedes hacer es que cargues un `DataTable` con la primera consulta y a ese `DataTable` ralizarle las mismas acciones que haces en la `BD`. Asignas ese `DataTable` a tu `DataGridView` y cada vez que realices un acción ejecutas luego `DataBind()` en tu `DataGridView`;

Comment: O has la actualización en memoria, con un BindingList, de esa forma se actualiza el dgv. Obvio tendrías que llevar control de guardar los cambios en la bdd.